# onItemLongClick listener does not work to a preference?

Tags: android

I want to create a list of contacts (just like the SMS app) and if the user clicks one of those contacts I will bring them to the SMSReply Class like this :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(SMSActivity.this, SMSReply.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

...and it's successful :D

But now, I want to bring my users to a preference when they long click a contact, so i just did the same thing like above but it's not working :

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent iMenu = new Intent("android.intent.action.PREFSCONTACT");
    startActivity(iMenu);
    return false;
}
```

I already made a Class and setContentView it to my prefs..so I use an intent(iMenu) to go to that Class..but it fails (it just doesn't do anything and when I release my mouse it goes to the SMSReply Class just like in `onItemClick()` method)

Comment: What do you mean when you say "It failed.", does the application crash or there's any errore/exceptions? You should paste those messages otherwise people will have no way of knowing what your problem is. Anyway, I think you should `return true` from the `onItemLongClick` method, which means you consumed the long click event.

Comment: yes, i don't realized that :D
Thanks Sir
Btw i have tried it before, and it's still same like above :D

Comment: SOMEONE..help me please..Thanks :D

Comment: You want to add a context menu, and then long click on items of the context menu, and go to another Activity, right? then first you have to create a context menu, see `onCreateContextMenu()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
mListView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```